# Building an android quiz without using unnecessary activities

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android programming and want to make a simple quiz that has around 50 questions. My problem is that I am unsure of how to do this without creating 50 individual layouts, java classes and activities. I would like each question to be different, and the format of the questions is multiple choice (A, B, C and D). Any helpful suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: one layout with one textview, four buttons (A,B,C,D) and change both the text and the text on the buttons for each other question.

Comment: Use a data list and change controls' values every time user clicks next.

Comment: @damian , how would I change the text after each question? 
Would an arraylist work to store the questions and answers, etc? Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy! Just create one acitivty and then update it's data every time user answers the question:

1) Changing TextView with question

2) Changing Buttons with answers

```
/*updating question
*questions is the list of questions obviously
*answers is the list of lists:) When you take a list from answers 
*you get a list with 
*4 items - they are the answers for current question
*/

public void updateQuestion() {
    mQuestionTextView.setText(questions.get(currentQuestionNum));
    mButtonA.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(0));
    mButtonB.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(1));
    mButtonC.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(2));
    mButtonD.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(3));
}

EDIT:

public ArrayList<String> getAnswers(int questionsNumber) {
     return ArrayList<String> currentQuestionAnswers = answers.get(questionsNumber);
}
```

Comment: How would I start by doing that? I understand having the textview and buttons on the first layout but I'm not sure how to change the questions text and buttons text. Would you recommend storing them in an array or something like that?

Comment: For the very beginning - yes, you can store them in ArrayList. And see updated answer.

Comment: Wow, that's great. Thanks for the code example too. I will try that out and see how I get on. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, you can ask another question in here comments, if you face a trouble with your quiz-app. And dont forget to upvote/mark as correct the answer, if you like it.

Comment: So, am I correct in saying I would do something like this in my MainActivity: ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameofTextView);
question.setText(questions.get(currentQuestionNum)); ?

Comment: Where currentQuestionNum is the int variable used to determine which question the user is on?

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and I keep getting an error when I'm setting the text buttons saying "the method (int) is undefined for the type string". E.g. mButtonA.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(0)); gives me the error.

Comment: As I said, answers is the list of lists, so it's actuall not ArrayList<String>, but ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Comment: How would I add the answers to the arraylist of arraylists? I've tried using the add() method, but that's not working. Neither is addAll().

Comment: Actually, it's okay. I figured out that I had to add the questions arraylist to the answers arraylist<arraylist<string>>. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can I ask another question? I've tried adding more questions to the arraylist and when I finish the second question and go on to the third, the app crashes. Giving an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Ok, i will modify my answer :)

Comment: Thanks. I can show you the code I have for adding the questions if that helps too?

Comment: public void updateQuestion(){
  questionTextView.setText(questions.get(currentQuestionNum));
  oneA.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(0));
  oneB.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(1));
  oneC.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(2));
  oneD.setText(answers.get(currentQuestionNum).get(3));
  currentQuestionNum++;
} Just after I increment the currentQuestionNum it throws the indexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: The getAnswers() method you suggested isn't working. It gives a suggestion to create a constant arraylist.

Comment: @user1831081 please post ALL your code here (edit your question) or to pastebin

Comment: Questions are only for questions, and answers for answers! http://pastebin.com/E4ra1Fw2

Comment: Thanks. So, if I want to keep adding questions, I just create a new arraylist instance each time?

Comment: Yes, of course. And remove goToSecondQuestion method. Replace it with nextQuestion. because you wont write 50 methods

Comment: Thanks. Haha, yes, I won't be wanting to write 50 methods!! Do you have any suggestions on how to check if the correct button has been pressed after every question?

Comment: @user1831081 if i were you i would create class Answer which has two field String answerText and boolean isCorrectAnswer; Then while you clicking button A it checks Answer that goes first in list of current answers and so on. Dont forget to randomly shuffle answers list BEFORE setting text for buttons

Comment: would you be able to give me a code example of the Answer class? Would it be something like: public class Answer{
       String AnswerText = "";
       boolean isCorrectAnswer = false;

  public Answer(String answerText, boolean isCorrectAnswer){
     this.answerText=answerText;
     this.isCorrectAnswer=isCorrectAnswer;
}
}

Then, in the other class:
Answer question1 = new Answer("Answer", true);

Comment: Yes, somethig like that + add getters and setters! And btw, "accept answer" means to press the tick below the answer's rating

Answer (score 1):

At every question, you can do something like this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
question.setText(current_question);
```

And for the multiple choice, if you are using a RadioGroup, you can have 4 textviews that correspond to each option and you can modify the text, depending on the question.

For recognizing which option has been selected, put this inside an onClickListener

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);



    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am setting the text in the textview after each new question and I'm using 4 normal "square/rectangle" buttons.

Comment: Then you dont even need a radioGroup. Please vote up and accept answer if you thought my answer was useful.

Comment: I tried to accept both your answer and @Semyon's but it says I need 15 reputations before I can vote up. Sorry.